# Fixing the FontSize and LineSpacing from the OptionInspector

Tags: formatting

I wonder if it is possible to fix the `FontSize` and `LineSpacing` from the OptionInspector. I did not manage to do it. That is, I introduced the desired values into the corresponding field of the OptionInspector and pressed the Apply button, but the values immediately returned to the default settings.

On the other hand, I remember to seem to have successfully done that few years ago.

I know the possibility to modify this by editing the StyleSheet. This my question is, if this may be modified from the OptionInspector.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>Return</kbd> after entering the number to finish editing the field. If you just click outside, the value is reset.

Comment: You are right, thank you.